# "redis\connection.py", line 756, in read_response raise response redis.exceptions.ResponseError: wrong number of arguments for 'set' command

Tags: python, django, caching, redis

I'm trying to store IP address in redis using django, but set method is not working.

**Exception:**

```
redis_env\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 756, in read_response
raise response
```

redis.exceptions.ResponseError: wrong number of arguments for 'set' command

**Here is my API in views.py:**

```
def cache_test(request):
    

    ip = str(request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR'))

    cache.set(ip,'2',timeout=22)
    print(ip)
    print(cache.get(ip))

    #print(radis_cache.get(1))


    return HttpResponse(str(cache.keys('*')))
```

**CACHES setting in setting.py**

```
CACHES = {
    'default'   :  {
        'BACKEND'   :      'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION'  :      'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/',
        'OPTIONS'   :{
                           'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
                }

    }
```

**Error:**

[image]

**It work with following but don't show anything on get:**

```
def cache_test(request):
    
    #radis_cache = radis_cache['default']

    ip = str(request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR'))

    cache.set(ip,'2',timeout=0)
    print(ip)
    print(cache.get(ip))

    #print(radis_cache.get(1))


    return HttpResponse(str(cache.keys('*')))
```

**I already try following but nothing work:**

```
cache.set(ip,'2')     # Error: wrong number of arguments for 'set' command

cache.set({ip:'2'})   #Error: missing 1 required argument
```

**Libraries list**

```
asgiref==3.4.1
Django==3.2.7
django-redis==5.0.0
psycopg2==2.9.1
pytz==2021.1
redis==3.5.3
sqlparse==0.4.2
```

Comment: `timeout=0` will actually cause it to not cache. Try to set it to for example a 300 seconds and see if it works

Comment: timeout  = 300 also gives error that wrong number of arguments for 'set' command. But it works with timeout = 0. Its strange but don't know why its happening.